# Messed up ACPI tables on HP Envy x360/Arch Linux

Tags: linux, laptop, arch-linux, acpi

I recently installed Arch Linux on my laptop, an HP Envy x360. For the better part of a year, I hadn't been able to get my install flash drive to boot, but yesterday I managed to get it up and running. However, I noticed a few problems pretty quickly.

Firstly, it can't detect the lid opening or closing. It doesn't send any ACPI events. I've tried picking them up through various methods, and none of them work. It does detect other events, like the power button being pressed or the volume up/down buttons being pressed.

Secondly, it will not wake up if I suspend it, no matter what I do. Pressing keys will make the screen turn on, but it remains black no matter what.

Thirdly, it will immediately wake up if I set it to hibernate.

This is very problematic because it means the laptop, once taken off the charger, will always be draining its battery as if it's being used, even if it's closed. I can't suspend or hibernate it, so my only option is to completely shut it down whenever I'm not using it.

This has led me to the conclusion that there's an issue with the ACPI table. I found [this site](https://iam.tj/prototype/enhancements/Windows-acpi_osi.html) documenting a very similar issue. I adapted the solution for UEFI by just adding the flags on boot in the boot loader, but that didn't fix anything, either.

So now, what I'm left with is a laptop that's virtually unusable and I have no idea how to fix it. According to the site I linked, ACPI tables on laptops are often messed with for Windows for some reason. Is there any way I can reset the ACPI table or fix it? I've looked for tools that might help me, but haven't found anything. [Here](https://hastebin.com/ugikamugen.coffeescript) is a dmesg dump, if that's of any help.

Any help and ideas are appreciated, because I'm out of ideas here.